# Can't create std::ofstream variable despite including <iostream>

Tags: c++, fstream, iostream

I am getting an ofstream error in C++, here is my code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

error from Dev-C++ 10

> C:\devp\main.cpp aggregate
> `std::ofstream OutStream' has
> incomplete type and cannot be defined

Answer (score 69):

You can try this:

```
#include <fstream>

int main () {
  std::ofstream myfile;

  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 33):

The file streams are actually defined in `<fstream>`.

Answer (score 7):

You may not be including the appropiate header file.

adding `#include <fstream>` at the beggining of your source file should fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you are including the wrong header file. There is a header <iosfwd> that is used for header files that need to reference types from the STL without needing a full declaration of the type. You still are required to include the proper header <iostream> in order to use the types in question.

Answer (score 0):

Include `fstream` header file that's it. Because `ofstream` & `ifstream` are included in fstream.

Answer (score -1):

Add `#include <fstream>`.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt", std::ios::out);
    myfile << "Writing this to a file\n";
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and see: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same error because I forgot to use `using namespace std;`
after including it, the problem was solved.

Comment: forgetting std would have resulted in compile error and not a runtime error