# Infile incomplete type error

Tags: c++, arrays, function, file-io

I am building a program that takes an input file in this format:

```
title author

title author

etc

and outputs to screen 

title (author)

title (author)

etc
```

The Problem I am currently getting is a error:

> "ifstream infile has incomplete type and cannot be defined"

Following is the program:

```
#include <iostream>              
#include <string>
#include <ifstream>
using namespace std; 

string bookTitle [14];
string bookAuthor [14];
int loadData (string pathname);         
void showall (int counter);

int main ()

{
int counter;  
string pathname;

cout<<"Input the name of the file to be accessed: ";
cin>>pathname;
loadData (pathname);
showall (counter);
}


int loadData (string pathname) // Loads data from infile into arrays
{
    ifstream infile; 
    int counter = 0;
    infile.open(pathname); //Opens file from user input in main
    if( infile.fail() )
     {
         cout << "File failed to open";
         return 0;
     }   

     while (!infile.eof())
     {
           infile >> bookTitle [14];  //takes input and puts into parallel arrays
           infile >> bookAuthor [14];
           counter++;
     }

     infile.close;
}

void showall (int counter)        // shows input in title(author) format
{
     cout<<bookTitle<<"("<<bookAuthor<<")";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057287/offstream-error-in-c

Comment: There's no such standard include file as `<ifstream>`. Your compiler should display an error. If it does not, check its options. You *do* want to have an error in such cases.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

File streams are defined in the header `<fstream>` and you are not including it.

You should add:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: The new error I get is:

no matching function for call to `std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open(std::string&)'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code with the previous error fixed Now I get a problem of the program crashing after I input the name of the text file.

```
#include <iostream>              
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

string bookTitle [14];
string bookAuthor [14];
int loadData (string pathname);         
void showall (int counter);

int main ()

{
int counter;  
string pathname;

cout<<"Input the name of the file to be accessed: ";
cin>>pathname;
loadData (pathname);
showall (counter);
}


int loadData (string pathname) // Loads data from infile into arrays
{
    fstream infile; 
    int counter = 0;
    infile.open(pathname.c_str()); //Opens file from user input in main
    if( infile.fail() )
     {
         cout << "File failed to open";
         return 0;
     }   

     while (!infile.eof())
     {
           infile >> bookTitle [14];  //takes input and puts into parallel arrays
           infile >> bookAuthor [14];
           counter++;
     }

     infile.close();
}

void showall (int counter)        // shows input in title(author) format
{

     cout<<bookTitle<<"("<<bookAuthor<<")";







}
```