# C++ txt file passing thru command line ( std::ifstream inFile has initializer but incomplete type)

Tags: c++, file-io, initializer

I am trying to read a `list.txt` file with multiple items (as below)

```
100/1 
111/1
115/2 
116/3 
120/1
```

through command prompt say `program.exe list.txt`  , so `argv[1]` will be the txt file `list.txt` (kept in cwd)
Then i need to separate `100/1` into `partname`=`"100"` and `rev_id`=`"1"` and run `do_something()`; similarly with `111/1` into `partname`=`"111"` and `rev_id`=`"1"` (in a loop).

The following is my code snippet. it gives a compilation error at `ifstream
std::ifstream`: "`inFile` has initializer but incomplete type."

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong here.

Thanks a lot !

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ifstream inFile (argv[1]);
    string partName;
    while (inFile)
   {
      getline(inFile, partName);
      cout <<endl<< partName << endl;
    std::string str = partName;
    char *cstr = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, str.c_str());

 char * partname=(strtok (cstr,"/"));
    char * rev_id = (strtok (NULL,"/"));
    //do something();
     printf(" \n Partname is %s \n",partname);
  printf(" \n Rev_id is %s \n",rev_id);
   }

inFile.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include header `<fstream>`.

You can find similar posts here. Little googling is enough.

[Infile incomplete type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816900/infile-incomplete-type-error)

[C++: variable 'std::ifstream ifs' has initializer but incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080231/c-variable-stdifstream-ifs-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type)